# jQuery select only tr/td in main table, not nested tables. 

Tags: jquery

I currently have a table with a nested table in it:

```
   <table class="datagrid" id="report">
       <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>item1</th>
          <th>item2</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr class="odd"> <-- on click from this level only 
        <td></td>  
        <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
         <table>
          <tr class="odd"> <-- not to be fired here
           <td></td>
```

etc table structure.

I am currently using the following jQuery, which fires on every `tr` regardless of the table level. How do I change it to only fire on the first level?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();

            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("#report tr").fadeToggle(600);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [child selector `>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to only select those `tr` elements that are a child of the *report* table’s `tbody`, for example:

```
$("#report > tbody > tr.odd")
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I new it was something really simple.

Answer (score 11):

with this solution it does not matter whether you have a tbody tag in between:

```
$('table').find('tr:first').parent().children()
```

Comment: My understanding is this :first will select only one from main table. However OP seems to looking for selecting all the tr from main table .

Comment: The correct understanding is that once the first `tr` tag is found then the parent of that is taken and then all children within will be returned. Thus all `tr` elements of the selected `table` will be returned

Comment: The more generic nature of this approach makes it better than the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: This may fail in some browsers that automatically add a <tr> to the thead too. I think `$('table').find('tbody:first').children()` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

You use the `>` selector to target only the direct descendant of an element. You have to target the implicit tbody element inside the table also:

```
$('#report>tbody>tr.odd')
```

Answer (score -1):

You want

```
$("#report>tr")
```

The `>` means direct descendant (child) rather than any descendant.

Comment: This won't work because `tr` isn't a DIRECT descendant of `table`. `tbody` is in between.